# Setting up Haskell OpenGL on Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: opengl, haskell

I'm having a difficult time figuring out the set of packages I need to get Haskell OpenGL working on Ubuntu 10.04.

Could someone please provide me with the list of APT packages and the list of CABAL packages I need to get to successfully start the OpenGL tutorial [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/OpenGLTutorial1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your easiest path would be to look at the dependencies of the [Debian OpenGL package](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libghc6-opengl-dev).

- libghc6-opengl-dev

Which depends on:

- libgl-dev
- libgl1
- libglu1
- libglu-dev

All part of the [Haskell Platform on Debian](http://packages.debian.org/sid/haskell-platform), which will be in Ubuntu in a few months.